# SQL - Aggregate Function for DATEDIFF and WHERE/HAVING

Tags: python, mysql, innodb, mysql-python

I'm trying to query a DB to find the closest date to the parameter I passed in.

I have a problem I've been working on in IRC and lists for a while and can't find a solution. I'm using a python DBAPI (sqlalchemy) and am accessing the data both through CLI and a Flask App (but this should not impact the SQL). The database is MySQL with an InnoDB engine.

The query will depend on the a factor called `target_expiration`, but for which the value will frequently not exist in the DB. I need to find which value is nearest. For example, I will pass in `target_date='2015-06-02'` and would expect it to return to me both the `2015-06-03` result and the `2015-06-01` result that is one day away from my `target_date`.

**Attempt at a solution**:

```
SELECT * FROM table1 HAVING MIN(ABS(DATEDIFF(table1.Expiration, 
'2015-06-02'))) = ABS(DATEDIFF(table1.Expiration, '2015-06-02'));
```

This returns no rows. I can run the same `MIN(ABS(DATEDIFF(...)))` to return a `scalar()` and it succeeds and prints a value.

I tried using the `HAVING` function in order to use an aggregate function. I'm looking to scan the DB and find out what is my closest Expiration date to my target date. If it's zero, I'm done - I've found the date and I then just want to return all dates that match. If it's a day away, I don't know if it's a day forward or a day backwards (I'll deal with adding more functionality to choose later, but for now I'd just like to return all values that are `n` days away forwards or backwards).

**Example Data:** table1

This is an extremely limited sample of the data, in reality I have ~40 columns and billions of rows, so speed is a factor.

```
+------------+-------------+-------+
| Expiration | ProductType | Price |
+------------+-------------+-------+
| 2015-06-01 |      2      |   25  |
+------------+-------------+-------+
| 2015-06-03 |      1      |   22  |
+------------+-------------+-------+
| 2015-05-28 |      1      |   22  |
+------------+-------------+-------+
| 2015-05-28 |      2      |   28  |
+------------+-------------+-------+
| 2015-05-28 |      1      |   22  |
+------------+-------------+-------+
| 2015-06-04 |      2      |   28  |
+------------+-------------+-------+
| 2015-05-25 |      1      |   22  |
+------------+-------------+-------+
| 2015-05-25 |      2      |   28  |
+------------+-------------+-------+
```

Comment: Your query is only going to find you entries that have `table1.Expiration = target_expiration`. (Assuming Expiration is a DATE data type.)

Comment: Ugh - you're right. This is only one variation of my attempts. Do I store the variable somehow in SQL instead of just iterating over attempts in python?

Comment: Meaning, do I store the result of `MIN(ABS(DATEDIFF(table1.Expiration, 
'2015-06-02')))`

Comment: I don't see how storing it would help, I am adding an answer now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a single result:

```
SELECT * 
FROM table1 
ORDER BY ABS(DATEDIFF(table1.Expiration, '2015-06-02')) ASC
LIMIT 1;
```

If you're worried about having a "tie":

```
SELECT * 
FROM table1 
WHERE ABS(DATEDIFF(table1.Expiration, '2015-06-02')) = (
   SELECT MIN(ABS(DATEDIFF(table1.Expiration, '2015-06-02')))
   FROM table1
);
```

Note however, **these queries will never be fast**; the 2nd requires every row in the table to be inspected twice, and in both the function usage prevents indexing from providing any help.

Answer (score 0):

How about simply

```
SELECT  *
    FROM  table1
    ORDER BY ABS(DATEDIFF(Expiration, '2015-06-02'));
```

Or, if the table is big, and you have `INDEX(Expiration)`, this should be faster:

```
( SELECT  *, 
        ABS(DATEDIFF(Expiration, '2015-06-02')) AS diff
    FROM  table1
    WHERE Expiration >= '2015-06-02'
    ORDER BY Expiration ASC LIMIT 1 )
UNION ALL
( SELECT  *, 
        ABS(DATEDIFF(Expiration, '2015-06-02')) AS diff
    FROM  table1
    WHERE Expiration < '2015-06-02'
    ORDER BY Expiration DESC LIMIT 1 )
ORDER BY diff 
LIMIT 1;
```